# Create a link within same sheet from top 10

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that I want to have a link to the cell within the same sheet.

I want to link the following Phone names to the second image cell.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/4ovzMpL.jpg]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/lWfbJ6z.jpg]

Above is a list of phones

I read this and attempted it but this did not work for me.

```
=HYPERLINK("#MyRange","Shift to there")
```

My formula in cell M2

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$70,MATCH(N2,$I$2:$I$70,0))
```

And this

```
=HYPERLINK(VLOOKUP(M2,'Copy of Phones DP'!phones,1,0),M2)
```

This one links me to a new tab and searches for the following

```
http://galaxy%20s9+%2064gb/
```

The expected outcome would be When I click on the phone name in column M it goes to the phone row in column C

EDIT:

Ok so I'm getting close

I use the following

```
=HYPERLINK("#" & CELL("address",INDEX(C2:C64,MATCH(M3,phoneName,0))),B5)
```

It does not go to the cell but the URL changes in Google Sheets to

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Krsba8iEQU10z/edit#$C$58
```

Comment: I might add also that the top 15 list in first image may change from time to time so it would be nice if this was dynamic in nature.

Comment: A question like this might be better suited to an Excel specific forum. This is a programming QA, you'll get better answers to VBA questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(M2:M11), 
 HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16nnuzNRx_kGGJm1EBVX7kBT2bfW1-2TYwSiuaLF-QIA/edit#gid=130953988&range=C"&
 VLOOKUP(M2:M11, {Sheet1!C2:C, ROW(Sheet1!C2:C)}, 2, 0), M2:M11), ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

The command you need is `CELL`

```
=HYPERLINK(CELL("address",INDEX(C2:C64,MATCH(M3,phoneName,0))),B5)
```

Comment: This opens up in a new window with nothing to display

Comment: I added the "#" infront of CELL and that works but now the link in my URL is like this

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Krsba8iEQU10z/edit#$C$58

This will not work with the $ in it

Comment: The answer you are looking for is likely here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44473/link-to-a-cell-in-a-google-sheets-via-url?newreg=7e6438b5564e4943b50ad8a65e556e7e